# Getting Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Tags: javascript, java, forms, web

I am using a java web-service for my project I am calling a "form" from my static js file like this

`redirectToLogout=function(user){ 
    var form = $('<form action="/b.html/"  name="vote" method="post" 
    style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="user" 
    value=\''+JSON.stringify(user)+'\'></input></form>');
    $(form).submit();
}`

I keep on getting this error `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected`

This seems to be only happening on chrome...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually insert the form into the DOM.

```
var $form = $('<form action="/b.html/" name="vote" method="post" 
    style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="user" 
    value=\''+JSON.stringify(user)+'\'></input></form>');
$('body').appendChild($form);

$form.submit();
```